# Could not locate in registry (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, registry

I'm running AnyPyTools as a package in an Anaconda environment. When I try to run the first commands of the AnyPyTools "getting started" jupyter notebook, I get an error that says "Could not locate AnyBody in registry". Any ideas on how to deal with that?

I tried uninstalling & re-installing AnyPyTools, with a shutdown in between, but still get the same error. Also, I can't find a separate AnyBody python package to install.

#### Version info:

- conda version : 4.10.3 conda-build version : 3.21.6
- python version : 3.8.12.final.0
- anypytools: version = 1.7.5 build=py38haa244fe_1 channel=conda-forge
- Windows 10 Version = 10.0.18363 Build = 18363

#### code

(from http://localhost:8888/notebooks/01_Getting_started_with_anypytools.ipynb)

```
from anypytools import AnyPyProcess 
    app = AnyPyProcess()
```

#### Error message:

```
 OSError: Could not locate AnyBody in registry
```

#### Trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anypytools\tools.py in get_anybodycon_path()
    461     try:
--> 462         abpath = winreg.QueryValue(
    463             winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "AnyBody.AnyScript\\shell\\open\\command"

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11000/586603320.py in <module>
      1 from anypytools import AnyPyProcess
----> 2 app = AnyPyProcess()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anypytools\abcutils.py in __init__(self, num_processes, anybodycon_path, timeout, silent, ignore_errors, warnings_to_include, fatal_warnings, return_task_info, keep_logfiles, logfile_prefix, python_env, debug_mode, use_gui, priority, **kwargs)
    537 
    538         if anybodycon_path is None:
--> 539             anybodycon_path = get_anybodycon_path()
    540         anybodycon_path = Path(anybodycon_path)
    541         if use_gui:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anypytools\tools.py in get_anybodycon_path()
    464         )
    465     except WindowsError:
--> 466         raise WindowsError("Could not locate AnyBody in registry")
    467     abpath = abpath.rsplit(" ", 1)[0].strip('"')
    468     abpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(abpath), "AnyBodyCon.exe")

OSError: Could not locate AnyBody in registry
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it doesn't work because it requires a sperate install of Anybody software which requires a paid license.